# How do I Index this View Properly?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, indexed-view

I have a table similar to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (Work_ID VARCHAR(9));
```

I need to be able to run the following query and unfortunately can not change the data type of the Work_ID column:

```sql
SELECT Work_ID
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE WorkID >= 100 AND WorkID <=200
```

This of course will give me an implicite conversion and cause a table scan (several million rows).

My thought was to put the following indexed view on it.

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Work_ID]
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
        SELECT  CAST(q.Work_ID as INT) as Work_ID 
        FROM dbo.SomeTable q
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [cl_vw_Work_ID] ON [dbo].[vw_Work_ID]
(
    [Work_ID] ASC
)
GO
```

When I now run

```sql
SELECT Work_ID FROM dbo.vw_Work_ID WHERE WorkID >= 100 AND WorkID <=200
``
I still get IMPLICIT CONVERSION and a table scan.  Any solutions?
```

Comment: Don't use a `varchar` field or don't use an integer parameter. This has nothing to do with indexed views. Besides, what you try to do is little different to creating an index over a computed column. An indexed view has to calculate and store the indexed values.

Comment: PS: You're using both `Work_ID` and `WorkID` when the table only has a `Work_ID` column. What's the correct name? Are you using or indexing the wrong column perhaps?

Comment: Does your query work correctly, if slowly, when you use `WHERE  WorkID >= '100' AND WorkID <= '200'` with strings instead of integers? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I made the example as simple as I could, the Work_ID vs WorkID was a typo, I realize that the table has VARCHAR, as stated, I can't change the table structure and the 100 and 200 were arbitrary numbers that I used for the example, they are parameters that are being passed to the query in real life and passing a varchar will not work because of the sorting by ascii values.  It is looking for number ranges.  I did not architect this mess, only trying to help the sever performance issues that bad design has caused.  I will try the TRY_CAST and NOEXPAND suggestion.

Comment: NOEXPAND did the trick.  THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRY_CAST` instead of `CAST` to avoid conversion errors. The resultant value will be `NULL` for invalid integer values. Also, add a `NOEXPAND` hint so to use the view index:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (Work_ID VARCHAR(9));
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Work_ID]
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
        SELECT  TRY_CAST(q.Work_ID as INT) as Work_ID 
        FROM dbo.SomeTable q;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [cl_vw_Work_ID] ON [dbo].[vw_Work_ID]
(
    [Work_ID] ASC
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable VALUES('111');
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable VALUES('xxx');
GO
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[vw_Work_ID] WITH(NOEXPAND) 
WHERE Work_ID = 0;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

We can index on the column using the same WHERE conditions as we want to use in the query. When we check with XML Stastics on we see that the query has been run on the index and has not done a table scan.
Please see the dbFiddle link for confirmation of the query plan.

> ```
> SET STATISTICS XML ON;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (Work_ID VARCHAR(9));
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable
> WHERE Work_ID >= '100' AND Work_ID <='200';
> ```

- The query plan shows a full table scan

> ```
> create index [cl_vw_Work_ID]
> on [dbo].[SomeTable](Work_ID)
> WHERE Work_ID >= '100' AND Work_ID <='200';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable
> WHERE Work_ID >= '100' AND Work_ID <='200';
> ```

- The query plan shows an index scan and no table scan

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70ce5689fbae26ea21a3de0f0c502054)*

- **UPDATE**
  following the comment that the values 100 and 200 are not fixed I have tried creating a virtual column casting the Work_ID to int and created an index on it. The query plan is showing a full table scan, even when I insert 4000 rows.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable
> ADD num_work_id AS  CAST(Work_ID AS INT)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> create index [cl_vw_Work_ID]
> on [dbo].[SomeTable](num_work_id)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable
> WHERE num_work_id >= '100' AND num_work_id <='200';
> ```

> Work_ID | num_work_id
> :------ | ----------:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6c3b29eaae435b7dc83479b549e51bb)*

with 4000 rows *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7492e7dabaabab200b8a267055875bb)*